# Where can I find the list of acceptable file type with FilePond?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I have a project with [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/) and I'm trying to have a validation if the file types are not acceptable.

but where can I find the list of the file type that I can use with `FilePond`.

```
      <FilePond
        acceptedFileTypes={['image/*', 'application/pdf']}
      />
```

I found out how to accept the `image` and `pdf` but I'm still looking for sample codes to accept the `.tiff`, `.docx`, `.txt`.

Does anybody know how?

#### It works!

```
      <FilePond
          acceptedFileTypes={[
          'image/*',
          'application/pdf',
          '.docx',
          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
          'text/plain',
        ]}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check [MIME Common types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

`.tiff` => `image/tiff`

`.docx` => `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

`.txt` => `text/plain`

Comment: `.tiff` and `.txt` work good but for `.docx` I needed to set simply like `'.docx'`! Thank you for your answer!